# Problem in Uploading file to path using PHP

Tags: php

I'm not unable to move the uploaded file to the desired path using move_uploaded function.
Please help me out.

I tried to change my syntax to something like this:-
          $destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
          $target_path = $destination_path . basename( $_FILES["profpic"["name"]);
Then also couldn't do it.

```
if(isset($_POST['otp-btn'])){


                   $otpa = $_POST['otp'];
                   $file_n = $_COOKIE['file_name'];


                  if($_COOKIE['otp'] ==  $otpa){

                                $destination = '/adhaar';


         if(!move_uploaded_file($_COOKIE['tmp'], "$destination/$file_n")){
            echo "<script>alert('File is not uploaded')</script>";
                                                        }
}
```

Every variable is fetching information(variables such as $_COOKIE['tmp'], $file_n) are not empty. I echoed it and it was carrying the information.

File is not getting uploaded.

Comment: Why would the name of the temp file you want to move come from a cookie in the first place? That makes very little sense - the info under what temp name the file was stored is only available to you in the script instance that is processing the request to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

```
 if(isset($_POST['otp-btn'])){


                   $otpa = $_POST['otp'];
                   $file_n = $_COOKIE['file_name'];


                  if($_COOKIE['otp'] ==  $otpa){

                                $destination = './adhaar';


         if(!move_uploaded_file($_COOKIE['tmp'], "$destination/$file_n")){
            echo "<script>alert('File is not uploaded')</script>";
                                                        }
 }
```

Try this.